# How does lauterbach trace32 print registers?

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I am just trying to understand how does lauterbach trace32 prints registers with r command. Also how does it set breakpoints. Basically how does trace32 extract/modifies live register values? Any documentation/ source scripts to understand the sequence?

Comment: Do you what to know, what you should do, to print core registers and to set breakpoints with TRACE32, or do you ask what TRACE32 does on the JTAG port, when you print registers and set breakpoints?

Comment: yes I wanted to know what TRACE32 does to print the registers and set breakpoints

Comment: Well, in this case I think I can't help you. If you'd like to know how a debugger works internally, I guess you have to contact the vendor directly. Furthermore I guess you question is highly specific to the debugged SoC. Maybe you chip manual also tells you how a debugger can read registers or set breakpoints - this is usually not a thing each debugger does differently.